# Can't render primefaces components?

Tags: java, jsf, spring-mvc, primefaces

I'm working on a Spring3/JSF2/Primefaces3.5 application:
The problem I'm facing is that some Primefaces components are not rendering in the browser.
Im begginer on spring framework and this is my fisrt attempt to integrate Primefaces into my webapp
this is index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

        <h:form>  

            <p:growl id="msg" />  

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">  

                <h:outputText value="I accept terms and conditions: " />  
                <p:selectBooleanButton value="#{formBean.value1}" onLabel="Yes" offLabel="No"/>  

                <h:outputText value="Subscribe me to newsletter: " />  
                <p:selectBooleanButton value="#{formBean.value2}" onLabel="Yes" offLabel="No" onIcon="ui-icon-check" offIcon="ui-icon-close">  
                    <p:ajax update="msg" listener="#{formBean.addMessage}"/>  
                </p:selectBooleanButton>  

            </h:panelGrid>  

            <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" />  

            <p:dialog header="Selected Values" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" widgetVar="dlg">  
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="display">  
                    <h:outputText value="Value 1: #{formBean.value1}" />  

                    <h:outputText value="Value 2: #{formBean.value2}" />  
                </h:panelGrid>  
            </p:dialog>  

        </h:form>

    </html>

and this is project tree and web.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <!-- Chargement du contexte de l’application Web -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <!-- Welcome page -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- JSF Mapping -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

this is servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gestion.projet" />


</beans:beans>
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <application>
        <el-resolver>
                org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the primefaces namespace on the xhtml page.

xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  is the correct one, what version of PF are you trying?

http://primefaces.org/gettingStarted - Try this basic example to see if it runs properly. How did you access the page? It needs to be picked up by the FacesServlet.